# Use Javascript to Play HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

How can I use **Javascript** to play an HTML5 `<video>`?

For example, play the video at a `onclick` event.

Comment: The [DOM API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#media-elements) is defined in the spec. You should be able to guess which method to call to play the video.

Comment: c'mon boys and girls...play nice..we were all learning once, and hopefully we are all still learning...this question is relevant, and makes sense to me. Barrel of crabs...

Comment: Yes, It's a good question for me too.

Comment: "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly". Are you kidding me?! How to play an HTML 5 video via javascript on click event? There's literally no simpler or more clear way to state it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add an event listener to your play button where it calls `videoElem.play()`

HTML:

```html
<video id='video'>
    <source src="your-video-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<button id='playVid'>Play</button>
```

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('playVid').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('video').play();
};
```