# How do I trigger videos to play when a user presses specific keys on the keyboard - Using HTML potentially looking at onkeypress

Tags: html, video, keyboard, keypress

I am very new to programming (this is my first attempt) and I am wishing to make a website where you can trigger videos using your keyboard (each key would be assigned to a different video). I am hoping to make something like this - http://patatap.com/

I have managed to layer my videos and for them top play and loop when opening the page however I can't find a way of getting a video to play when a key is pressed! What would be the best and simplest way of doing this - I have looked at "onkeypress" however I am not sure how to use it!

I'll post my code so far below!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #backplate {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -4;
            }

            #twinkle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -3;
                mix-blend-mode: screen
            }

            #skel-walk {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }

            #clap-test {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: 0;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }

            #chord-1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -2;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }
        </style>


        <script>

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


        <!--BACKPLATE-->


        <img id="backplate" src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Back_Plate00000.png">  


        <!--SKEL-WALK-->


        <video id="skel-walk" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_Skeleton_Walk_TTP.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>


        <!--CLAP-TEST-->


        <video id="clap-test" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>


        <!--CHORD-2-->


        <video id="chord-1" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Chord_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>


        <!--TWINKLE-->


        <video id="twinkle" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Twinkle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12201488/901048

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to get a video to play/pause using the space bar.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video_id');   
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e || window.event).keyCode === 32){
        video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause();
    }
};
```

You can assign the keycode to be triggered by a different key. And manipulate the code inside of the if to do what you would like on a key press.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quick, ill give this a go!! under which section would this code need to go? In the script part?

Comment: @ThomTTP Yes in the script tags. You might want to read up a little on JavaScript and make sure you are referencing your HTML elements using their id attribute

Comment: Cheers for the heads up! I've put it in the script section and placed the correct id for the video within the brackets ("video_id") and kept {video.play()} but it is unresponsive, had a few tweaks but I can't get it working. Do I have to place place some code in between the <video></video> section of the code to for it to work?

Comment: try putting the script in your body tag under all of your videos. It might not be loading on time

Comment: My man you are a genius, slapped it in between the <video></video> and its working a dream! Is there any way to get the video to restart when pressing the key? At the moment I have to wait for the video to end before it can be pressed again! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: video.load(); this might work. inside of your if statement

Comment: I couldn't get it to work popped in video.currentTime = 0 and works a dream! One more annoying thing and I'll leave you be, When I place the script in between another video - changing the video.id and the keycode - only the lowest script in the code will trigger a video and the others will not work, have you got any thoughts on how to solve this? I was thinking I could call each script much like CSS?

Comment: I would have it in an external file with all of your JS much like referencing an external style sheet https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I'll look into this!

Comment: I recommend also adding `e.preventDefault();` in the if block - this will make it so the website won't scroll down when you press space.