# How do i trigger a link with no id via console

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am simply trying to trigger a link with no id via console. I have tried multiple scenarios and none seem to work. It is a link with lots of classes and no id.

```js
$('.videoHolder').find('a.icon-play').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoHolder hover">
  <div class="videoDisplay">

   <video class="persistentNativePlayer nativeEmbedPlayerPid" poster="data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%08%02%00%00%00%90wS%DE%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%13%00%00%0B%13%01%00%9A%9C%18%00%00%00%07tIME%07%DB%0B%0A%17%041%80%9B%E7%F2%00%00%00%19tEXtComment%00Created%20with%20GIMPW%81%0E%17%00%00%00%0CIDAT%08%D7c%60%60%60%00%00%00%04%00%01'4'%0A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82"
      id="pid_kaltura_player" kentryid="1_4u0ocu4u" kuiconfid="" kwidgetid="" kpartnerid="" preload="none" width="560" height="395" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></video>
    <div class="videoShadow"></div>
    <div class="mwEmbedPlayer" id="kaltura_player" style=""></div>
  </div><a tabindex="-1" href="#" role="button" class="comp largePlayBtn  largePlayBtnBorder icon-play" aria-label="Play clip" data-order="1" data-plugin-name="largePlayBtn" style="display: flex; opacity: 1;">Mylink</a></div>
```

Comment: as your code , the meaning is that you want use the  a link to control the video to playing or pause?

Comment: @Vzupo unfortunately i don't see a link in your html only an anchor.

Comment: yes i want to click the anchor to play the video

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201488/use-javascript-to-play-html5-video

Comment: if you want to trigger the video by useing the a link ,you should declare a click function to the a link ,and then triggler it , at your code ,there is no click function but the a default click function instand,so rewrite your a link click function first

Comment: i cannot modify the code its simply pasted here to show what I am challenged with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `<a>` tag and fire `.click()`.

To demonstrate this, I made a `test()` which will print `MyLink Clicked....` in the console if the link is clicked.

```js
function test() {
  console.log("MyLink Clicked....");
}

document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
```

```html
<div class="videoHolder hover"><div class="videoDisplay"> 

    <video class="persistentNativePlayer nativeEmbedPlayerPid" poster="data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%08%02%00%00%00%90wS%DE%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%13%00%00%0B%13%01%00%9A%9C%18%00%00%00%07tIME%07%DB%0B%0A%17%041%80%9B%E7%F2%00%00%00%19tEXtComment%00Created%20with%20GIMPW%81%0E%17%00%00%00%0CIDAT%08%D7c%60%60%60%00%00%00%04%00%01'4'%0A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82" id="pid_kaltura_player" kentryid="1_4u0ocu4u" kuiconfid="" kwidgetid="" kpartnerid="" preload="none" width="560" height="395" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></video><div class="videoShadow"></div><div class="mwEmbedPlayer" id="kaltura_player" style=""></div>
</div><a tabindex="-1" href="#" role="button" class="comp largePlayBtn  largePlayBtnBorder icon-play" aria-label="Play clip" data-order="1" data-plugin-name="largePlayBtn" onclick="test()" style="display: flex; opacity: 1;">Mylink</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I undestand your trouble, the a link you can't click it by yourself ,you can only do it by add some click functon ,then trigger it , and you can try it with this code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="videoHolder hover">
    <div class="videoDisplay">

        <video class="persistentNativePlayer nativeEmbedPlayerPid"
               poster="data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%01%00%00%00%01%08%02%00%00%00%90wS%DE%00%00%00%01sRGB%00%AE%CE%1C%E9%00%00%00%09pHYs%00%00%0B%13%00%00%0B%13%01%00%9A%9C%18%00%00%00%07tIME%07%DB%0B%0A%17%041%80%9B%E7%F2%00%00%00%19tEXtComment%00Created%20with%20GIMPW%81%0E%17%00%00%00%0CIDAT%08%D7c%60%60%60%00%00%00%04%00%01'4'%0A%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82"
               id="pid_kaltura_player" kentryid="1_4u0ocu4u" kuiconfid="" kwidgetid="" kpartnerid="" preload="none"
               width="560" height="395" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></video>
        <div class="videoShadow"></div>
        <div class="mwEmbedPlayer" id="kaltura_player" style=""></div>
    </div>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" role="button" class="comp largePlayBtn  largePlayBtnBorder icon-play"
       aria-label="Play clip" data-order="1" data-plugin-name="largePlayBtn"
       style="display: flex; opacity: 1;">Mylink</a></div>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.videoHolder').find('a.icon-play').on('click',function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');
    });
    $('.videoHolder').find('a.icon-play').click();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you add `$('.videoHolder').find('video').play()` it should also play the video.

Comment: yeah, it's more directly